# use object items within another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use an object which was created in an initial setup list with in another function to create another object. Hope this makes sense. The full code is at the bottom of this question.

The part which is not working is below where a user inputs a name from an auto list. From what they enter a new list will be created from the item name but I wanted to import the values stored in the original object from the name entered but it comes up undefined.

If I console log the value ie Carrot.cal the original val is displayed within console

This is the part i am having trouble with

```
  $("#add_food").click(function(){
    var food_name = $('#food_name').val();
    var cal = food_name.Cal;  // This should be the cal value from initial list above
    newFood = new My_list(food_name,100,cal,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,5); // values are test values apart from variable cal and food_name
  })
```

Below is the full code if you select Carrot in the input box the top table has Calories as undefined which should be 41

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   // carrot = {name:'Carrot', cal:41, A:334, B6:5, B12:9, C:9, D:0, calcium:3, Iron:1, mag:3};
  
  Carrot = new food('Carrot',41,334,5,0,9,0,3,1,3);
  butternut_squash = new food('Butternut Squash',45,212,10,0,35,0,4,3,8);
  Apple = new food('Apple',52,1,0,0,7,0,0,0,1);

  function food(Name, Cal, A, B6, B12, C, D, Calcium, Iron, Mag){
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Weight = 100;
    this.Cal = Cal;
    this.A = A;
    thidd_B6 = B6;
    this.B12 = B12;
    this.C = C;
    this.D = D;
    this.Calcium = Calcium;
    this.Iron = Iron;
    this.Mag = Mag;
// create the main table of all the items
    var newRow = "<tr><td>"+this.Name+"</td><td>"+this.Cal+"</td><td>"+this.A+"</td><td>"+this.B6+"</td><td>"+this.B12+"</td><td>"+this.C+"</td><td>"+this.D+"</td><td>"+this.Calcium+"</td><td>"+this.Iron+"</td><td>"+this.Mag+"</td></tr>";
    $("#food_list").append(newRow);
  }
// Auto Fill function
  $( function(){
    var foodList = ["Carrot", "Apple", "Butternut Squash"];
    $("#food_name").autocomplete({
      source: foodList
    });
  })
// Add new item to USERS list
  $("#add_food").click(function(){
    var food_name = $('#food_name').val();
    var cal = food_name.Cal;  // This should be the cal value from initial list above
    newFood = new My_list(food_name,100,cal,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,5); // values are test values apart from variable cal and food_name
  })
  function My_list(Name, Weight, Cal, A, B6, B12, C, D, Calcium, Iron, Mag){
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Weight = Weight;
    this.Cal = Cal;
    this.A = A;
    this.B6 = B6;
    this.B12 = B12;
    this.C = C;
    this.D = D;
    this.Calcium = Calcium;
    this.Iron = Iron;
    this.Mag = Mag;
    var newRow = "<tr><td>"+this.Name+"</td><td>"+this.Cal+"</td><td>"+this.A+"</td><td>"+this.B6+"</td><td>"+this.B12+"</td><td>"+this.C+"</td><td>"+this.D+"</td><td>"+this.Calcium+"</td><td>"+this.Iron+"</td><td>"+this.Mag+"</td></tr>";
    $("#my_list").append(newRow);
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src=foodList.js></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--Add food box with auto fill function-->
  <div align="right">
    <button type=button id="add_food">Add Food</button>
    <input type=text id="food_name"/>
  </div>
  <table id="my_list">
    <tr>
      <th>Food</th>
      <th>Calories</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B6</th>
      <th>B12</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>Calcium</th>
      <th>Iron</th>
      <th>Magnesium</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="food_list">
    <tr>
      <th>Food</th>
      <th>Calories</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B6</th>
      <th>B12</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>Calcium</th>
      <th>Iron</th>
      <th>Magnesium</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It would make it a LOT easier for people to help you if you followed standard JavaScript conventions: Constructor functions are initially capped (`Food`, not `food`) and property names start with a lowercase letter. Please also see [mcve] -- the above isn't at all minimal.

Comment: The problem is here `var food_name = $('#food_name').val();`, the `food_name` is just a string value in your autocomplete, not the object you defined.

Comment: I thought by adding the string name to a variable with the appended key would work as I did with { var cal = food_name.Cal; } but as you stated this does not work. Still looking for a work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a reference to all the food types you create, as properties of an object like this...

```
// create an empty object to hold the food objects - do this outside document.ready
var foods = {};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // create the food objects
    foods["Carrot"] = new food('Carrot',41,334,5,0,9,0,3,1,3);
    foods["Butternut Squash"] = new food('Butternut Squash',45,212,10,0,35,0,4,3,8);
    foods["Apple"] = new food('Apple',52,1,0,0,7,0,0,0,1);

    // etc..
```

Then, to access the food objects later...

```
var food_name = $('#food_name').val();
var food = foods[food_name];
var cal = food.Cal;
```

To make this require less maintenance, you could also populate the autocomplete from the available food objects in the `foods` object...

```
$("#food_name").autocomplete({
    source: Object.keys(foods)
});
```

If you do this then the food names are automatically added to the autocomplete list when you create them - no need to do both.

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)

Comment: And the second part for auto fill work well to will have to learn how this works :) thanks

Comment: I've just updated that as I made it longer than it needed to be.  `Object.keys(*object*)` creates an array of the property names of an object.  In this case it's the names of your food types, which is exactly what the autocomplete needs.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list to store your object. Then after getting autocomplete value, mapping this value with the value store in your list to get the object.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   // carrot = {name:'Carrot', cal:41, A:334, B6:5, B12:9, C:9, D:0, calcium:3, Iron:1, mag:3};
  
  Carrot = new food('Carrot',41,334,5,0,9,0,3,1,3);
  butternut_squash = new food('Butternut Squash',45,212,10,0,35,0,4,3,8);
  Apple = new food('Apple',52,1,0,0,7,0,0,0,1);
  
  
  var FOOD_LIST = {'Carrot': Carrot, 'Apple': Apple, 'Butternut Squash': butternut_squash};

  function food(Name, Cal, A, B6, B12, C, D, Calcium, Iron, Mag){
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Weight = 100;
    this.Cal = Cal;
    this.A = A;
    thidd_B6 = B6;
    this.B12 = B12;
    this.C = C;
    this.D = D;
    this.Calcium = Calcium;
    this.Iron = Iron;
    this.Mag = Mag;
// create the main table of all the items
    var newRow = "<tr><td>"+this.Name+"</td><td>"+this.Cal+"</td><td>"+this.A+"</td><td>"+this.B6+"</td><td>"+this.B12+"</td><td>"+this.C+"</td><td>"+this.D+"</td><td>"+this.Calcium+"</td><td>"+this.Iron+"</td><td>"+this.Mag+"</td></tr>";
    $("#food_list").append(newRow);
  }
// Auto Fill function
  $( function(){
    var foodList = ["Carrot", "Apple", "Butternut Squash"];
    $("#food_name").autocomplete({
      source: foodList
    });
  })
// Add new item to USERS list
  $("#add_food").click(function(){
    var food_name = $('#food_name').val();
    var cal = FOOD_LIST[food_name].Cal;  // This should be the cal value from initial list above
    newFood = new My_list(food_name,100,cal,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,5); // values are test values apart from variable cal and food_name
  })
  function My_list(Name, Weight, Cal, A, B6, B12, C, D, Calcium, Iron, Mag){
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Weight = Weight;
    this.Cal = Cal;
    this.A = A;
    this.B6 = B6;
    this.B12 = B12;
    this.C = C;
    this.D = D;
    this.Calcium = Calcium;
    this.Iron = Iron;
    this.Mag = Mag;
    var newRow = "<tr><td>"+this.Name+"</td><td>"+this.Cal+"</td><td>"+this.A+"</td><td>"+this.B6+"</td><td>"+this.B12+"</td><td>"+this.C+"</td><td>"+this.D+"</td><td>"+this.Calcium+"</td><td>"+this.Iron+"</td><td>"+this.Mag+"</td></tr>";
    $("#my_list").append(newRow);
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src=foodList.js></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--Add food box with auto fill function-->
  <div align="right">
    <button type=button id="add_food">Add Food</button>
    <input type=text id="food_name"/>
  </div>
  <table id="my_list">
    <tr>
      <th>Food</th>
      <th>Calories</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B6</th>
      <th>B12</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>Calcium</th>
      <th>Iron</th>
      <th>Magnesium</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="food_list">
    <tr>
      <th>Food</th>
      <th>Calories</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B6</th>
      <th>B12</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>Calcium</th>
      <th>Iron</th>
      <th>Magnesium</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I copy the original code & it does not work as well. But the answer is to create a mapping list that store the food object & its name.

Answer (score 0):

So you will need to setup a getter for the food object that takes in a param and gets the fields related to that food type. Then you can use the results of this to populate the row in the table.

```
$("#food_name").autocomplete({
      source: foodList,
      select: function(event, ui) { -------> Select function for autocomplete widget
        console.log('Food: ', ui)
        // Getter for the food object that 
      }
    });
```

The autocomplete widget comes with a select function that you can use to get the value

```
var foodGetter = function(food) {
  // Get food row. Without food object, can't really help here but it should be a case of returning an array of the values associated with that food
  foodObj = {carrot: [weight, calories, ...], butternut_squash: [...]}
  return foodObj[food]
}
```

Then you use the returned array to populate table.